# Display an uploaded image in a webform, rather than the filename

Tags: 8, webforms

**Background**: I'm using the profile module to hold user data but that makes an unpleasant UX for updating user info. So I'm using a single-page webform to offer the editable user data. The user data is provided as default data before it's rendered and the webform does not store information, when submitted the data is copied back to the right profiles and the submission deleted.

**Problem**: The user's profile picture is displayed as the file name, and I want the picture but I can't see any setting for that under the image element. What I get is this:
[image: What I don't want]
What I want (with better styling, obviously):
[image]

**Is this possible with out-of-the-box webform elements?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to either alter the output to the [file-link.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21templates%21file-link.html.twig/8.6.x) template. You can do this by replacing the `link` variable with an image via [template_preprocess_file_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/template_preprocess_file_link/8.6.x).

- or -

Alter the rendered output of the managed_file element which is a little more difficult.

---

So I decided to investigate how one would add a preview to the managed file upload element. I realized that most of the needed functionality already existed in the Webform module. I created [Issue #3018806: Allow authenticated users to preview file uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3018806) and I should have a working patch in the next day or so.

Comment: The latest release of the webform module allows you to customize the image upload's preview for authenticated users.

Comment: You, sir, are a hero.